# Move folder to another folder based on their match

Tags: text-processing, directory, rename

I have a text file as such:

```
    Order,Site_ID
besnard.sim@gmail.com-10132016-093523-554,AR-Slu
```

The column 'Order' contain the name of the folder that I want to move to the corresponding folder (same row in the text file) which is shown in the 'Site_ID' column. This is an example for only one folder to be moved. In this example, I want to move the folder'besnard.sim@gmail.com-10132016-093523-554' to the folder 'AR-Slu'. The information contain in the table are the name of the folder but do not have path information of the folders. However, the two folders are in the same parent folder. Anyone would know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For blank-separated values

(as in the initial version of your question)

```
(cd /parent/folder && tail -n +2 | xargs -L 1 mv --) < file
```

The `tail` is to skip the header.

With `-L 1`, `xargs` runs one `mv` command for each 1 line of its input with the *words* on that line passed as arguments to `mv`.

For `xargs`, *words* are blank delimited (whether it's all blanks or only space and tab depends on the `xargs` implementation), though `xargs` also recognises `"`, `'` and `\` as quoting operators that can be used to escape those blanks or each other.

You could also use a `while read` shell loop:

```
(
  cd /parent/folder || exit
  unset -v IFS
  read skip_header <&3
  ret=0
  while read src dst rest_ignored <&3; do
    mv -- "$src" "$dst" || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"
) 3< file
```

Again, for `read` and with the default value of `$IFS` (or after `unset IFS`), words are space or tab separated. `\` can be used to escape those or itself or continue lines on the next physical line.

### For CSV files

If the file is a CSV file (values separated by `,` and possibly surrounded by quotes), then you could run that loop in the `ksh93` shell and use the `-S` option of it's `read` builtin for CSV parsing:

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
(
  cd /parent/folder || exit
  IFS=,
  read -S skip_header <&3
  ret=0
  while read -S src dst rest_ignored <&3; do
    mv -- "$src" "$dst" || ret=$?
  done
  exit "$ret"
) 3< file
```

You can take off the `-S` option so it also works in other POSIX shells like `bash` which would work as long as CSV quoting is not used in the file.

Or you could use a CSV parsing module in `perl` or other scripting language:

```
(cd /parent/folder && perl -C -MText::CSV -e '
  $c = Text::CSV->new;
  $ret = 0;
  $c->getline(STDIN); # skip header
  while (($src, $dst) = @{$c->getline(STDIN)}) {
    system "mv", "--", $src, $dst;
    $ret = 1 if $?;
  }
  exit $ret;') < file
```

Comment: I guess there is a need to specify the path of the two directories somewhere no?

Comment: Just did the edit.

Comment: @SimonB, see edit.

Comment: I have this error message: 'xargs: 1: No such file or directory'. If I do 'tail -n +2 file', the output looks like 'besnard.sim@gmail.com-10132016-093523-554,AR-Slu' Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @SimonB. I overlooked the fact that `-l` was not portable (no longer standard) (and with GNU `xargs`, one needs `-l1` instead of `-l 1`). `-L` is the standard (Unix, not POSIX) equivalent. What operating system are you on?

Comment: I am in Linux. I just run the `(tail -n +2 | xargs -L 1 mv --) < file.csv` command line and I have this error message `mv: missing destination file operand after ‘besnard.sim@gmail.com-10132016-093523-554,AR-Slu’`

Comment: @SimonB, looks like your values are comma separated while you showed them as blank separated in your question. Please edit your question to show the content of the file in its real format  (a csv file?) not as rendered by some application. (note that Linux is not an OS, it's just the kernel found in some Unix-like and non-Unix-like OSes)

Comment: Just did the edit

Comment: And Yeah it is a csv file